# unLoading shared library loaded via JNI in Java

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

How can i unload shared library that loaded throught

```
   static {
            System.loadLibrary("mylibrary");}
    }
```

I want to destroy all C++ sources in onStop();

My Activity is getting anr after restart in  System.loadLibrary("mylibrary");

Comment: Unloading a library isn't really a concept.  And it wouldn't free up C resources if you could-  C is NOT a garbage collected language, there is no automated way to free up its resources.

Comment: ... So practice better resource management.  The moment you get JNI involved, you take on that responsibility, which Java otherwise does a fairly good job of insulating you from.

Comment: Search "dynamic memory allocation in C++" in Google.

Comment: If i correctly understood you, 1) i must create destructor call for my JNI-objects and call it in onStop() of my Activity?  2) Say me please, undestroyed c++ objects can cause anr in  loadLibrary after restart (non stable behaviour)? Or i must try to find mistakes in other places =) Thanks for your attention to my problem.  p.s. For transfering objects i use this dropbox framework https://github.com/dropbox/djinni/) In https://github.com/dropbox/djinni/blob/master/support-lib/jni/djinni_main.cpp we have 2 calls (secondary onUnload call is not working)